# Elastic IP on application deployed using Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm a bit confused about the use of the Elastic IP service offered by Amazazon Web Services. I guess the main idea is that I can switch to a new version of the web application with no downtime following this simple procedure:

1. Deploy the new version on a new EC2 instance
2. Configure the new version properly and test it using a staging DB
3. Once properly tested, make this new version use the live DB
4. Associate the Elastic IP to this instance
5. Terminate all the useless services (staging DB and old EC2 instance)

Is this the common way to deploy a new version of a web application?

Now, what if the application is scaled on more instances? I configured the auto scaling in the Elastic Beanstalk settings and this created a load balancer (I can it see in the EC2 section of the AWS Management Console). The problem is that I apparently cannot associate the Elastic IP with the load balancer, I have to associate it with an existing instance. To which instance should I associate it to? I'm confused...

Sorry if some questions may sound stupid but I'm only a programmer and this is the first time I set up a cloud system.

Thank you!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

[Elastic Load Balancing (ELB)](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) does not work with [Amazon EC2 Elastic IP addresses](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1346), in fact the two concepts do not go together at all.

### Elasticity via Elastic Load Balancing

Rather, ELB is usually used via [CNAME records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) (but see below), and this provides the first level of elasticity/availability by allowing the aliased DNS address to change the IP of the ELB(s) in use, if need be. The second level of elasticity/availability is performed by the load balancer when distributing the traffic between the EC2 instances you have registered.

Think of it this way: The CNAME never changes (just like the *Elastic IP address*) and the replacement of EC2 instances is handled via the load balancer, [Auto Scaling](http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/), or yourself (by registering/unregistering instances).

This is explained in more detail within Shlomo Swidler's excellent analysis [The “Elastic” in “Elastic Load Balancing”: ELB Elasticity and How to Test it](http://shlomoswidler.com/2009/07/elastic-in-elastic-load-balancing-elb.html), which in turn refers to the recently provided [Best Practices in Evaluating Elastic Load Balancing](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1636185810492479) by AWS, which confirm his analysis and provide a good overall read regarding the *Architecture of the Elastic Load Balancing Service and How It Works* in itself (but lacks the illustrative step by step samples Shlomo provides).

#### Domain Names

Please note that the former limitation requiring a CNAME has meanwhile been addressed by respective additions to [Amazon Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/) to allow the root domain (or *Zone Apex*) being used as well, see section *Aliases and the Zone Apex* within [Moving Ahead With Amazon Route 53](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/05/moving-ahead-with-amazon-route-53.html) for a quick overview and [Using Domain Names with Elastic Load Balancing](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-domain-names-with-elb.html?r=3319) for details.

### Elasticity via Elastic Beanstalk

First and foremost, [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) uses Elastic Load Balancing in turn as described above. On top if that, it adds application lifecycle management:

> AWS Elastic Beanstalk is an even easier way for you to **quickly deploy
>   and manage applications** in the AWS cloud. You simply upload your
>   application, and Elastic Beanstalk automatically handles the
>   deployment details of capacity provisioning, load balancing,
>   auto-scaling, and application health monitoring. [...] *[emphasis mine]*

This is achieved by adding the concept of an *Environment* into the mix, which is explained in the [Architectural Overview](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.concepts.architecture.html):

> The environment is the heart of the application. [...] When you create
>   an environment, AWS Elastic Beanstalk provisions the resources
>   required to run your application. AWS resources created for an
>   environment include one elastic load balancer (ELB in the diagram), an
>   Auto Scaling group, and one or more Amazon EC2 instances.

Please note that *Every environment has a CNAME (URL) that points to a load balancer*, i.e. just like using an ELB on its own.

All this comes together in [Managing and Configuring Applications and Environments](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.html), which *discusses some of the most important features of AWS Elastic Beanstalk in detail, including usage examples using the AWS Management Console, CLI, and the APIs*.

#### Zero Downtime

Its hard to identify the most relevant part for illustration purposes, but [Deploying Versions With Zero Downtime](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html) precisely addresses your use case and implies all required preceding steps (e.g. [Creating New Application Versions](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.deployment.html) and [Launching New Environments](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.environments.html)), so reading section *AWS Management Console* might give you the best overall picture how this platform works.

Good luck!

Answer (score 14):

In addition to the options described in Steffen's awesome answer, Elastic Beanstalk seems to have very recently **enabled Elastic IP** as an option if you don't need the full features of an Elastic Load Balancer (like auto-scaling beyond one instance).

I describe the option in [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17725512/454094). Elastic Beanstalk now allows you to choose between two [Environment Types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-types.html), and the *Single-instance* option creates an Elastic IP.

[image: Dropdown with options "Single instance" and "Load balancing, autoscaling".]

---

I think using an ELB will be the preferable option in most cases, but e.g. for a staging server it is nice to have an alternative that is less complex (and cheaper).

Comment: Be warned that the EIP gets released and a new one assigned if you rebuild the Elastic Beanstalk environment...which is kind of dumb.

Comment: However, fortunately, it is the same EIP when we eg. change type of the instance.

Comment: I found it much easier to setup HTTPS for a beanstalk app with the "Load Balancing, autoscaling" option.

Answer (score 4):

Apologies for answering a post a few years later, however for those that do actually need a set of static IP addresses on an ELB, it is possible to ask AWS nicely to add what they call 'Stable IP' addresses to an ELB, and thereby give it that static IP address feature.

They don't like doing this at all of course - but will if you can justify it (the main justification is when you have clients that have IP whitelist restrictions on outbound connections via their firewalls and are completely unwilling to budge on that stance).

Just be aware that the 'auto scaling' based on traffic option isn't straight forward any more - AWS would be unable to dynamically add more ELB endpoints to your ELB as they do with the out of the box solution and you have to go through the pain of opening up new IP addresses with your customers over time.

For the original question though, EB using an ELB to front EC2 instances where static IP addresses are not actually required (no client outbound firewall issues) is the best way as per the accepted answer.

Comment: Did you have the same problem and got AWS added "stable IP" for you? (I just to make sure AWS has that kind of service if requested)

Comment: Yes - we have ELBs with static (stable) IP addresses assigned.

Comment: Starting with september 2017 you can use network load balancer (which support EIP) within Beanstalk - https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/details/

Comment: And even more crazy: if you want all of the features of the application load balancer with a EIP/static IP via the network load balancer, you can just run both plus a lambda to tie them together: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/using-static-ip-addresses-for-application-load-balancers/

Answer (score 2):

In the case that none of the above solutions works, one alternative is to attach a NAT gateway to a private subnet and associate an EIP with the NAT gateway. In this case you’re able to use the ELB, use auto-scaling, and have a reserved EIP.

This is a bit more expensive though, especially for large throughput use cases.  Also, SSHing into the instance to debug becomes a bit more complex.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [a post](https://ajsharp.com/elastic-beanstalk-elastic-ips/) describing how to accomplish this using a Cloudwatch rule when a new instance is launched, and a lambda function. Here's the lambda function code:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ec2 = new AWS.EC2();
const PROD_ENV_NAME = 'my-prod-env-name';

// Example Event
// {
//   "version": "0",
//   "id": "ee376907-2647-4179-9203-343cfb3017a4",
//   "detail-type": "EC2 Instance State-change Notification",
//   "source": "aws.ec2",
//   "account": "123456789012",
//   "time": "2015-11-11T21:30:34Z",
//   "region": "us-east-1",
//   "resources": [
//     "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:instance/i-abcd1111"
//   ],
//   "detail": {
//     "instance-id": "i-abcd1111",
//     "state": "running"
//   }
// }

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  console.log("EVENT:", event);

  // The newly launched instance ID.
  const instanceId = event.detail['instance-id'];

  // Fetch info about the newly launched instance
  const result = await ec2.describeInstances({
    Filters: [ { Name: "instance-id", Values: [instanceId] } ]
  }).promise()

  // The instance details are buried in this object
  const instance = result.Reservations[0].Instances[0];
  const isAttached = instance.NetworkInterfaces.find(int => int.Association.IpOwnerId !== 'amazon');

  // Bail if the instance is already attached to another EIP
  if (isAttached) {
    console.log("This instance is already assigned to an elastic IP")
    return { statusCode: 200, body: '' }
  }

  // In elastic beanstalk, the instance name gets assigned to the enviroment name.
  // There is also an environment name tag, which could be used here.
  const name = instance.Tags.find(t => t.Key === 'Name').Value;

  // Only assign EIPs to production instances
  if (name !== PROD_ENV_NAME) {
    console.log('Not a production instance. Not assigning. Instance name:', name)
    return { statusCode: 200, body: ''}
  }

  // Get a list of elastic IP addresses
  const addresses = await ec2.describeAddresses().promise();

  // Filter out addresses already assigned to instances
  const availableAddresses = addresses.Addresses.filter(a => !a.NetworkInterfaceId);

  // Raise an error if we have no more available IP addresses
  if (availableAddresses.length === 0) {
    console.log("ERROR: no available ip addresses");
    return { statusCode: 400, body: JSON.stringify("ERROR: no available ip addresses") }
  }

  const firstAvail = availableAddresses[0]
  try {
    // Associate the instance to the address
    const result = await ec2.associateAddress({
      AllocationId: firstAvail.AllocationId,
      InstanceId: instanceId
    }).promise();

    console.log('allocation result', result)

    return { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify('Associated IP address.') };
  } catch (err) {
      console.log("ERROR: ", err);
  }
};
```

Comment: That is so amazing! WOW! Big thanks, I had to associate static IP with beanstalk due to outbound traffic and it works like magic!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the environment as a Single Instance as stated in the already accepted answer, or if you want to use an Elastic IP that you have already created, you can do the following.

Inside of the `.ebextensions` folder at the root of your project, make a file called `setup.config` and paste in the following:

```
container_commands:
    00_setup_elastic_ip:
        command: |
            export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID={YOUR-ACCESS-KEY-ID}
            export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY={YOUR-SECRET-ACCESS-KEY}
            export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1    
            INSTANCE_ID=$(ec2-metadata -i)
            words=( $INSTANCE_ID )
            EC2_ID="${words[1]}"
            aws ec2 associate-address --instance-id $EC2_ID --allocation-id {eipalloc-ID-TO-THE-IP}
```

All you have to do is replace the 3 parts contained inside of the `{}` and you are good to go. This will replace the IP of your Elastic Beanstalk instance with the Elastic IP of your choosing.

The parts contained in `{}` are (get rid of the {} though, that is just there to show you which parts to replace with your info):

1. Your AWS Access Key ID
2. Your AWS Secret Access Key
3. the allocation ID of the Elastic IP you want to assign to your Elastic Beanstalk environment's instance.

Comment: It did not work, any other ideas? I have a single instance environment other than going through the NAT

Comment: Id have to see your setup.config file. You have one right? You also could make the instance a single environment (not using load balancers) and then instance should get its own elastic IP

Comment: it is a single instance and I want to attach a specific EIP to it.
this is my setup.config the same as yours
container_commands:
    00_setup_elastic_ip:
        command: |
            export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=1235
            export 
   AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=1234
            export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1    
            INSTANCE_ID=$(ec2-metadata -i)
            words=( $INSTANCE_ID )
            EC2_ID="${words[1]}"
            aws ec2 associate-address --instance-id $EC2_ID --allocation-id eipalloc-1234