# Is it possible to associate a specific elastic IP to an Elastic Beanstalk application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-ip

My problem: Elastic beanstalk environments automatically gets a new elastic IP when created, and it's not possible to force the use of an existing elastic IP when creating a new environment. Even associating an existing beanstalk environment with a different elastic IP than the environment was created with, does not seem to work. (It automatically re-assigns the old elastic IP address again)

An important requirement for the environment is to be able to use A record to point to the environment, and that A record must not be changed if the environment is rebuilt or terminated and then re-created.

In other words, my wish is to **maintain an IP for the environment even if I need to re-create it, and preferably not to be forced to use a custom domain.**

I'm not finding a way solve this using beanstalk, so the solution will probably be to use cloudformation template instead.

I would really like an good answer from someone with more AWS knowledge than me, to prevent switching to cloudformation without cause :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your EB environment just a single instance? In other words do you not have a load balancer? Are you using Route53 for DNS?

Comment: why do you want the IP? what's wrong with simply using the myapp.elasticbeanstalk.com cname?

Comment: Yes, it's a single instance and the instance is hosting a web application that redirects traffic from DNS-providers. That is also the reason why IP is preferable than CNAME (in the future Route53 will be used instead, but for now we need a temporary solution)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elastic IP on application deployed using Elastic Beanstalk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475287/elastic-ip-on-application-deployed-using-elastic-beanstalk)

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem? I have a single instance environment and I need to attach a specific EIP to it but elastic beanstalk is not letting me do it