# Static IP for AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment with load balancer for Tableau Trusted Authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, tableau-api, elastic-ip

I have an Elastic Beanstalk environment with load balancer. Also I have an hosted zone associated with the load balancer in order to access the environment via custom domain name.

Now I want a static IP to use in Tableau Trusted Authentication. I am confused. I can't figure out from where I can get the required static IP.

The answer accepted on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475287/elastic-ip-on-application-deployed-using-elastic-beanstalk) is 5 years old and things have changed since then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elastic IP on application deployed using Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475287/elastic-ip-on-application-deployed-using-elastic-beanstalk)

Answer (score 2):

Sadly there is no way to auto asign an Elastic-ip on a load balancer since AWS only provides support for the DNS.

But there is another solution, to add a script that auto asign an ip to an instance on boot. As the next references suggest.

https://support.asperasoft.com/hc/en-us/articles/216129788-Server-on-Demand-with-EIP-and-Autoscale#prereqs

https://blog.cloudthat.com/auto-attach-elastic-ip-to-ec2-classic-instance-for-autoscaling/

https://github.com/skymill/aws-ec2-assign-elastic-ip

You need to do the next steps:

1. Set aside as many elastic ip as the max number of instances in your Auto Scaling Group
2. Create an instance with the current Elastic Beanstalk  [AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html)
3. Install  [aws-ec2-assign-elastic-ip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aws-ec2-assign-elastic-ip)  using python's pip.
4. Add the current script to the instance

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   #
   # This script is launched at boot, and assigns an AWS elastic ip.

   AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=#<acces_key_value>#
   AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=#<Secret_key_Value>#

   #Regions Virgina: us-east1   Oregon: us-west2 ...
   AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=#<EB_ENV_REGION>#

   #Set of valid IP comma(,) separated
   VALID_IP_VALUES=<IP_VALUE>,<IP_VALUE>,<...>


   /usr/local/bin/aws-ec2-assign-elastic-ip --region  $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --access-key $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID --secret-key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY --valid-ips $VALID_IP_VALUES
   ```
5. Add this script at /etc/rc.local

   ```
   bash /usr/local/bin/auto-assign-eip.sh
   ```
6. Create a new base  [AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html) using this instance, and set it as your EB AMI.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to access the elastic beanstalk application using Static IP? If you want to access your application using static IP then go and spin up a EC2 and deploy your application. The assign a static Elastic IP to that instance. Elastic IP is a static public IP which wont change unless you release it. For more about AWS Elastic IP see the below link.

[AWS Elastic IP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html)

Comment: I tried assocating an elastic IP to ec2 instance but it didn't work. I guess I need to associate IP to elastic beanstalk load balancer.