# Is it possible to create an auto scaling Elastic Beanstalk without a load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have an application which consists of an API and many microservices. The API writes to queues from which the microservices are listening. We currently have 25 microservices - none of which need load balancers. At the cost of nearly 5k per year, we'd like to do without these microservice load balancers if possible. The difficulty is that these microservices need to be autoscaled based on CPU usage - so simply setting the application to single-instance environment as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014046/elastic-beanstalk-without-elastic-load-balancer) won't cut it.

Is there any way to have an autoscaling elastic beanstalk group which does not have a load balancer? We're using CloudFormation to describe our deployments and would like to remove the load balancer via our cloudformation template. I've gone through the [command option descriptions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html) and can't seem to find anything which fits this use case.

Comment: I do not think you can have auto scaling without load balancing on an elastic beanstalk; however you can create an autoscaling group of ec2 instances from a launch configuration which do not require a load balancer.

Comment: Just curious, why are you scaling on the CPU usage of the microservices instead of the size of the SQS queue that's being consumed?

Comment: @jbird we're still tossing around options - we thought it would be more standardized if we used CPU usage as certain microservices take longer to process messages than others. This way we can have global scaling settings (and add new microservices with out any deployment configuration).

Comment: @cscan Thanks! You can always have multiple scaling policies to find what works best for your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a worker tier in Elastic Beanstalk. So no loadbalancer would be needed. This page describes it in detail.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the current console GUI enforces a load balancer now for multiple instance "worker" environments.